# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 125: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I'm quite new to coding and trying to crack a password with the help of a .txt file.
This is my code so far:

```
import pyautogui
import random

dictionary = ()

real_pwd = pyautogui.password('Enter password: ')




# posibilities = len(chars) ** len(real_pwd)
# guess_pwd = ""
password = ""

with open("TinyButMighty.txt", "r") as wordlist:
    for line in wordlist:
        password = line.strip()
        print("denied:", str(password))
        if password == real_pwd:
            print("\nAccess Granted: ~ ", "".join(password))
            break
```

However when i run it with the TinyButMighty.txt i get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 125: invalid start byte
```

If i make a short list of words myself it doesn't run into any trouble.

Does anyone have an idea on how to surpass this problem?

Comment: It seems like your file can't be decoded in `utf-8`. Did you write the file yourself?

Comment: Your input seems to be in an other encoding as UTF-8, which is the default on Python 3. You can give the `encoding` argument to the `open()` call to adjust it to the right encoding. In most iso-8859 encodings `0xb2` is a `²`.

Comment: Try ```open("TinyButMighty.txt", "r", encoding='latin-1')```.

Comment: Note that if the file's *actual* encoding isn't really Latin-1, this will simply hide the error and allow - nay, force - the program to produce garbage.